# Is it possible to nest ASP.NET Timers?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a Timer on my ASP.NET web page that refreshes page content in certain intervals. Is there a way to nest another timer inside it so that its Tick Event handler is only called when the nested Timer's interval has elapsed? The main Timer actually shows different page content altogether, but I want the nested Timer to update content in the page before the main Timer changes the page. I do not want to interfere with the main Timer's functionality; instead, the main Timer should update as a result of the nested Timer updating. Any ideas?

EDIT: Instead of actually nesting Timers themselves, is there a way to create sub-intervals that will operate within an outer interval for one Timer?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Pages live on the client and can only be refreshed eg by a Javascript call, *not* a server side timer. Besides, any .net objects generated during a request are orphaned and garbage collected after a request finishes, which makes timers a very bad idea - they may well end up calling disposed objects. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: As I mentioned, the main Timer is refreshing a part of the page in certain intervals. The nested Timer should refresh another part of the page in sub-intervals of the main Timer's intervals. The main Timer should update when the nested Timer is finished updating.

Comment: Probably a good idea to show some markup/code

Comment: An ASP.NET Timer is an AJAX extension control, so isn't it technically making an implicit JavaScript call?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is a Timer control in Web Forms which can use JavaScript to trigger a postback and fire an event. Not that I recommend using that, but that appears to be what's being used here.

Comment: It's definitely not my preferred way of doing it either, but this project was already underway when I was assigned to it. I was just wondering if anyone had any clever ideas to make this approach work. I'm definitely not an expert on the ASP.NET web pages approach.